# Free download manager for Windows 10

Tags: gratis, windows-10, download-manager

I want a free or open source good download manager, no adware, no spyware, no bloatware or malware and a good browser integration.

There's only 1 duplicate question, and it's for Windows 8.1, they recommend DAM but AFAIK it's not compatible with Windows 10, and Windows 10 smart screen complains about it.

- IDM isn't free.
- Last time I used FDM, on Windows 7, it wasn't that good and hadn't
  had good browser integration.
- I used to use eagleget but I'm afraid it's now trying to install
  malware.
- Orbit infected with a malware too.
- It's hard to install uget on Windows and no Chrome integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend recommended [XDM](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xdman/), but I couldn't get it to work with chrome, so I ended up using [Ninja](https://vpnscout.org/ninja-download-manager) downloader which has a [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-ninja/gklhnpfkcfpkjcihhjbgmhgkcajamlmd?hl=en) extension and a [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/download-ninja-free-download-m/) extension and opera; and maybe others. (You could also download from [filehippo](http://filehippo.com/download_download_ninja/) which I prefer when I don't know or trust the original website)

The bad news is that i tried downloading avira offline installer, around 220mb, and i paused and I resumed and paused and resumed, the file continued downloading but was corrupted. Maybe it's not related to Ninja, but just be aware that maybe just maybe Ninja forces the file to resume but doesn't preserve its integrity.

Another inconvenience with the chrome extension is that when you click download, both the chrome download dialog and ninja get opened, it would be nice if only the ninja window popup, without the chrome one. And It can't monitor the system and detect download links, meaning it has to be opened for the links to get added to ninja. I haven't tried it on firefox yet.

That said, Ninja is the fastest free downloader I tried, orbit was faster maybe, but now orbit is full of malware, and I think it's dead.